# Angular child route on Lazy Loaded module does not load

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Not sure do I do everything right. But the thing is: when I navigate to some child routes of component from lazy loaded module it simply does not load. It reloads home component from Lazy Loaded Module.

app-routing.component.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'intel', loadChildren: () => import(`./intel/intel.module`).then(m => m.IntelModule)},
  {
    path: 'planet-detector',
    loadChildren: () => import('./planet-detector/planet-detector.module').then((m) => m.PlanetDetectorModule)
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'space', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', component: BlackHoleComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

planet-detector-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DetectorComponent, children: [
      { path: 'first', component: FirstChildComponent},
      { path: 'second', component: SecondChildComponent}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PlanetDetectorRoutingModule { }
```

So in the example as above when you put: 'http://localhost:4200/planet-detector/first' it loads DetectorComponent component instead of FirstChildComponent (url points to 'http://localhost:4200/planet-detector/first').

I noticed that when I change PlanetDetectorRoutingModule to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DetectorComponent },
  { path: 'first', component: FirstChildComponent },
  { path: 'second', component: SecondChildComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PlanetDetectorRoutingModule { }
```

Then it works fine. 
And mb one more question. What are the benefits of these children route separation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When routes are declared in the children property, it means that they should be rendered as a child of that component.

So for that route to be rendered, there needs to be a `<router-outlet>` in the `DetectorComponent`.

Routes listed in children follow this rule:

> There are important differences in the way the router treats these child routes.
>
> The router displays the components of these routes in the RouterOutlet of the ParentComponent, not in the RouterOutlet of the AppComponent shell.

Comment: Glad i could help, could you also accept the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers